# DateFormatter doesn't work Swift 3

Tags: swift, date, swift3, formatting, nsdateformatter

I'm trying to convert this date "07:05:45 PM" to "19:05:45", this code does not work, I did not found a solution in other questions about date, the code:

```
 Import Foundation
 let string = "07:05:45 PM"
 let dateFormatter = DateFormatter ()
 dateFormatter.locale = Locale (identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
 dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"
 let date = dateFormatter.date (from: string)
 print (date)
```

I tried

```
 dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm:ss"
 dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm:ss a"
 dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm"
```

I removed "PM" and tried:

```
 dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm" 
 dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm:ss" // that code is the only who worked, but doesn't solves the format problem
```

Comment: `"hh:mm:ss a"` should work for parsing

Answer (score 0):

You need to read with a DateFormatter that uses "a" at the end, and then don't just print the date with `print(date)`, you need to use another DateFormatter that uses a 24-hour clock format ("HH") and no AM/PM.

Answer (score 0):

You should do it like this:

```
let givenString = "07:05:45 PM"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm:ss a"

if let date = dateFormatter.date (from: givenString) {
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"

    let desiredFormattedString = dateFormatter.string(from: date) // "19:05:45"
}
```

Simply, your given date format is *"hh:mm:ss a"* and the required one is *"HH:mm:ss"*. By setting the appropriate formats (using `dateFormatter`), `desiredFormattedString` string should contains the desired formatted date for you.

Note that for getting the format of 24-hour clock convention, you should let the hours as `HH`, -obviously- `hh` represents 12-hour clock convention.